# UISlider with sound effect and vibration

Tags: iphone

I need to do a lot of things with UISlider. First of all I want to know what are all the things are possible and what are not. Please give me ideas for the doable ones.

I need to add a slider control in my iPhone application (that should resemble the one which is displayed in the iphone when the phone is getting charged).

1. Can the round button of the UISlider be changed to any other shape. Can any image be added on top of that round button?
2. When the UISlider is being moved, we need ad a sound effect(for example car stating sound) and when the sliding ends the sound should be stopped. is this possible? if yes, please gimme ideas to do this. 3. vibration should also happen while sliding (possible?)

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you can help me thru answering to some of the questions ateleast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these can be done via the public API. Read the docs :-)

1. The button is called the "thumb image"; there's a property to replace the image.
2. Assign a delegate and set the 'continuous' property on the slider.

See the Application Programming Guide for more on delegates.

Answer (score 1):

As far as question number 2, just write up the methods to accomplish playing a sound and vibrating and then have them fire when the value changes on the slider.